# Undefined index data type tinyint and nchar

Tags: php, mysql

i have table with 2 primary key and 1 foreign key. the problem is when i want to insert data to table, but something error just happen.

this is my mysql relation table 
[image: my sql table]

datatype PiorityPhonePerson is tinyint and CodePhonePerson is nchar.

and this is my php data :

```
<?
include "new.php";

$ID_Person              =  $_POST['IDPerson']; 
$Number_Phone_Person    =  $_POST['NumberPhonePerson']; 
$Piority_Phone_Person   =  $_POST['PiorityPhonePerson']; 
$Code_Phone_Person      =  $_POST['CodePhonePerson']; 


$response           =  array();

if (isset($ID_Person)               &&
isset($Number_Phone_Person)     &&
isset($Piority_Phone_Person)    &&
isset($Code_Phone_Person)       
) 
 {

$query      = "INSERT INTO T_Person_Phone 
                (
                ID_Person,
                Number_Phone_Person,        
                Piority_Phone_Person,   
                Code_Phone_Person
                )
                VALUES 
                (
                (SELECT ID_Person FROM T_Person
                where ID_Person     = '$ID_Person'),

                '$Number_Phone_Person', 
                '$Piority_Phone_Person',
                '$Code_Phone_Person'
                )
                ";

$hasil      = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query,$response);
    if($hasil)
{   

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User successfully created.";

}   else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Eksekusi error.";    
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

    }   else 
    {
    $response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "failed to save.";
    }
// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

when i try to execute,it can't be insert into my table.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query in the INSERT it doesn't make sense to do that if you are selecting the value you are giving to the query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO T_Person_Phone (
         ID_Person,
         Number_Phone_Person,
         Piority_Phone_Person,
         Code_Phone_Person
         )
         VALUES(
         '$ID_Person',
         '$Number_Phone_Person',
         '$Piority_Phone_Person',
         '$Code_Phone_Person')"
```

Comment: sory but you code not success again. is that any problem with my table?

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you sure those values you are inserting are set?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the error?

Without knowing the exact error we would just be stabbing the problem in the dark. Could you please stick these two lines at the top of your PHP page?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Let us know what's the error is and then we can suggest :)

Comment: sory,where i should put that code. i put that on top before include "new.php"; , just error like before. like this Notice: Undefined index: PiorityPhonePerson in C:\xampp\htdocs\person_phone_xml.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: CodePhonePerson in C:\xampp\htdocs\person_phone_xml.php on line 7

Comment: The problem is your values are not getting set for the following two lines:   
$Piority_Phone_Person   =  $_POST['PiorityPhonePerson']; 
$Code_Phone_Person      =  $_POST['CodePhonePerson']; 

Check to make sure $_POST['PiorityPhonePerson']; and $_POST['CodePhonePerson']; have values in them.